# regex to remove all text with a conditionated pattern

Tags: regex

Is there an easy way to remove specific parts of a string based on a pattern? For example, change `'hello\todelete5001\world\todelete4002\'` to `'hello\world\'`

Where `'todelete####'` is the pattern (Using vb.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `"todelete\d+\\"` with an empty string.